# GMSPlacePickerViewController issue in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mapkit, google-places-api

I was using `GMSPlacePickerViewController` for selecting a place, it was working fine before iOS 13. After the update of `iOS 13` `GMSPlacePickerViewController` is not working. It always showing an error page

> Can't load search results

I have enabled `Map` and `Google Place API` but still showing same error.
I have search every where for the solution of this, no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's Place Picker was [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration#place-picker-deprecation) in January 2019 and was turned off in July 2019.

> **Place Picker is no longer available**
>
> The Place Picker was deprecated on January 29, 2019. It was turned off
>   on July 29, 2019, and is no longer available. Continued use will
>   result in an error message. The new SDK does not support the Place
>   Picker.

However, migrating to the new Places SDK for iOS will allow you to use the other Place services that the SDK offers such as [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete). There's also a public feature request for a Place Picker widget in Google's issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128304760).

Hope this helps!